# What does it mean to spread points out as much as possile given that each point as its own range?

Tags: math

I need help defining/clarifying a problem I am trying to solve.

I have n points in one dimension. Each point has its own range that it can move between. They cannot move outside of that range. I need to "spread" the points out as much as possible. I want to maximize the distance between all adjacent points. What is a more formal way to say this?

[image]

Using a smaller example:
[image]

I can move the left and right points to the sides as much as possible. Then I can find the midpoint of this distance and move the middle point to that midpoint as much as possible.
[image]

I have maximized the average distance between all points but I have also minimized the variance of the distances as well.
These seem like the two core restraints I need to "spread out" the points as much as possible. I eventually need to develop an algorithm that can do this with an arbitrary number of points.

Am I correct that I need to maximize the average distance of all points while also minimizing the variance of these nearest  neighbor distances?

Comment: I wou,d descrbe it as maximsing the minimum distance.

Comment: I doubt we as a community can help you make that fuzzy concept more formal without more background on what you want to achieve. You might want to average the arithmetic mean of all the distances, or the geometric mean, or the sum of squared distances, or bring all distances as close as possible to total length divided by number of points, or draw maximal circles around each point that don't contain other points then optimise their properties. It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. You might also want to clarify whether the order of points has to remain fixed.

Comment: Well you are already helping. So there are multiple way to "spread" out these points as much as possible. Order does not matter. Points can move freely within their ranges.

If I spread the extreme points as much as possible, changing the inner points does not change average of arithmetic mean right?

However, using sum of squared distances, might be what I want. Unfortunately, I don't have the expertise to know what I need right now.

Comment: One thing to note about maximising minimum distance: a couple of neighboring points with small ranges near one end of the line can determine the minimum distance, and then all of the other points, with large ranges, have a lot of freedom. They can spread out, or crowd together, and as long as they don't get closer than those two points at the end, the metric doesn't care.